# Is it useful to await last instruction

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I have seen the following code and was wondering if, apart from forcing the method to have the `async` keyword, it is useful to specify the await on the last instruction ? Example

```
async example(){
  //... whatever code

  //Last instruction
  await functionReturningAPromise()
}
```

Note that here I suspect the **return is missing** but even with the return my question still stands.

```
async example(){
  //... whatever code

  //Last instruction
  return await functionReturningAPromise() //Is this useful ? or should we return directly
}
```

I personally see no real interest.

Comment: My understanding is that you need to either `await` *or* `return` the method call to ensure it's part of the promise chain, but don't need both. If you do neither, just call the method then implicitly `return undefined`, I don't think it becomes part of the same promise chain.

Comment: `return await ...` generates warnings in some ES linters - it's  (usually) unnecessary.

Comment: good explanation here - https://jakearchibald.com/2017/await-vs-return-vs-return-await/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is my attempt to answer my own question with only code. My conclusions are

1) I would disagree with the statement that `return await` is redundant outside of try/catch blocks. It will change the returned value of `example()` if called with `await`

2) Putting the `await` on the last statement will guarantee that if I `await example()` anything called after will be done *after* `functionReturningAPromise()` has resolved (as @Kristianmitk had pointed out).

3) Calling an async function with `await` does *NOT* work as `Promise.all` if you have multiple promises launched inside it (and not `await`-ed inside).

See results of tests 3/4/5 I get the log of the slow async function *after* I get the result.

```js
function asyncSlow(testName){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('slow is done from' + testName)
        resolve('slow-' + testName);
      }, 300);
    });
}

function asyncFast(testName){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('fast is done from' + testName)
        resolve('fast-' + testName);
      }, 100);
    });
}

async function test1(){
  await asyncSlow('test1')
  await asyncFast('test1')
}

async function test2(){
  await asyncSlow('test2')
  return await asyncFast('test2')
}

async function test3(){
  asyncSlow('test3')
  return await asyncFast('test3')
}

async function test4(){
  asyncSlow('test4')
  return asyncFast('test4')
}

async function test5(){
  asyncSlow('test5')
  asyncFast('test5')
}

async function main(){
  const res = await test1()
  console.log('res = ' + res)
  
  const res2 = await test2()
  console.log('res2 = ' + res2)
  
  const res3 = await test3()
  console.log('res3 = ' + res3)
  
  const res4 = await test4()
  console.log('res4 = ' + res4)
  
  const res5 = await test5()
  console.log('res5 = ' + res5)
}

main()
```

And this is what the output looks like :

```
slow is done fromtest1
fast is done fromtest1
res = undefined
slow is done fromtest2
fast is done fromtest2
res2 = fast-test2
fast is done fromtest3
res3 = fast-test3
fast is done fromtest4
res4 = fast-test4
res5 = undefined
slow is done fromtest3
fast is done fromtest5
slow is done fromtest4
slow is done fromtest5
```

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense if you want to surround the last instruction with a try-catch block to handle errors.

```
async example(){
  //... whatever code

  //Last instruction
  try {

   return await functionReturningAPromise()
  } catch(error) {
     // error handling
  }
}
```

If not, adding an `await` right after a `return` just introduces an unnecessary promise but yields the same result.

---

Without using a `return` it is useful to use an `await` in case you want to ensure that code that is executed after your call to `example()` will not be called before `functionReturningAPromise()` is settled.

Comment: In your second comment, are you implying that il will turn `example` to be kind of synchronous by ensuring any function called after will wait for `functionReturningAPromise()` to resolve even if not calling `example` with the `await` keyword ?

Comment: no, you will always need an `await` (or .then(...)) to make sure your subsequent code won't be executed before the settlement of `example`. I wanted to point out that the last `await` will have an impact when `example` will settle to its final state.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers (about try/catch) are interesting. It also makes sense because it alters the stack trace of the function if the function inside throws.

That is, `example` will show in the stack trace if you await `functionReturningAPromise` inside it it and it will not if you don't. So if you like being able to debug code I recommend keeping the await.=

Comment: If anyone thinks that the behaviour should be changed let me know and I'll bring it up in a meeting with the v8 team.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so - `await` is like a breakpoint. All the code that is in the `await`ed function runs before anything below the `await`. With the last call in a function, this wouldn't really matter, so it's easier just to do:

```
async function doStuff() {
    await thingOne();
    await thingTwo();
    thingThree(); //You can put await here if you want to, but it's not necessary, 
                  //even if it is asynchronous / returns a Promise
}
```

Comment: If `thingThree()` returns a promise, wouldn't `doStuff()` resolve before it finishes? I would thing that using an `await` would be required here, to allow for `thingThree()` to finish before `doStuff()` resolves.

Comment: It's the last instruction - so why would it matter?

Comment: If it was the last in the whole chain, then it wouldn't matter (apart from readability, maybe), but if `doStuff()` was going to be called somewhere where you want to wait for it to complete, then not using an `await` would resolve it early, which could be problematic if it wasn't intended.

Comment: @ZachBarham but surely you're using `await doStuff()` in which case the calling code will be the one waiting for the resolution of the promise.

Comment: It will, but it would just wait for `thingOne()` and `thingTwo()` because they're being `await`ed, but `thingThree()` isn't and its promise isn't being returned.

Comment: I'd expect the code example would do the same thing as `thingOne().then(() => { return thingTwo(); }).then(() => { thingThree(); });` - it won't wait for `thingThree()` because its promise goes knowhere